# How do I declare an optional target in automake?

Tags: automake

In my `Makefile.am` file I have something like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo bar

foo_SOURCES = foo.cpp

bar_SOURCES = bar.cpp
```

I am interested in having `bar` only compiled when I do a `make bar`, not when I do a `make all`. But I want `foo` always compiled. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The file you describe looks like a Makefile.am, which is not an autoconf file.  Automake is a completely different tool.

Comment: That's true. Can automake be used without autoconf?

Comment: It is common to use autoconf without automake, but very rare to use automake without autoconf.  I suppose it could be done, but automake is definitely designed to be used with autoconf.

Comment: I've edited the question according to those comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want do declare a program can be built (i.e. the target must be emitted by Automake), but should not be built by `make all` or `make check`, you can simply declare it as `EXTRA_PROGRAMS`.

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
EXTRA_PROGRAMS = bar
foo_SOURCES = foo.cpp
bar_SOURCES = bar.cpp
```